# android not getting editText value at run time in inner class

Tags: android

I have certain problem . I am creating an expendable List with custom tableLayout as child of expendableList. The Table Layput has 1 textView and 3 EditText in each row.

Now , The problem is that the editTexts in TableLayout does not detect text entered at run time. It gives blank value from editText. Please find the attached Code and suggest me suggestion to overcome the problem.

Main problem lies is the editText in gettabledata() methos shows isInEditMode "False". Can you please help how we can set IsInEditMode "true" at runtime.

```
package dus.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VarietyDetailsActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {
    TextView tv;

    EditText r1, r2, r3;
    TableLayout table;
    String[] States;
    String year;
    String[] listval = { "Candidate Variety", "Referencer variety 1",
            "Reference Variety 2", "Reference Variety 3" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);

        year = getIntent().getStringExtra("year").toString();
        System.out.println("Year in details activity:::::::" + year);
        States = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("States");

        setContentView(R.layout.variety_details);

        List groupList = new ArrayList();
        Map groupData = new HashMap();
        System.out.println("listval[i]:::::" + "Candidate Variety");
        groupData.put("text2", "Candidate Variety");

        groupList.add(groupData);

        Map groupData1 = new HashMap();
        System.out.println("listval[i]:::::" + "Reference Variety 1");
        groupData1.put("text2", "Reference Variety 1");

        groupList.add(groupData1);

        Map groupData2 = new HashMap();
        System.out.println("listval[i]:::::" + "Reference Variety 2");
        groupData2.put("text2", "Reference Variety 2");

        groupList.add(groupData2);

        Map groupData3 = new HashMap();
        System.out.println("listval[i]:::::" + "Reference Variety 3");
        groupData3.put("text2", "Reference Variety 3");

        groupList.add(groupData3);

        List childList = new ArrayList();
        List childList1 = new ArrayList();
        Map childMap = new HashMap();
        childMap.put("States", "States");
        childMap.put("R1", "R1");
        childMap.put("R2", "R2");
        childMap.put("R3", "R3");
        for (int i = 0; i < States.length; i++) {
            childMap.put(States[i], States[i]);
            // childMap.put("Green", "Green");
            // childMap.put("Purple", "Purple");
        }

        childList1.add(childMap);

        childList.add(childList1);
        childList.add(childList1);
        childList.add(childList1);
        childList.add(childList1);

        String[] str = new String[States.length + 4];
        str[0] = "States";
        str[1] = "R1";
        str[2] = "R2";
        str[3] = "R3";
        for (int j = 0; j < States.length; j++) {
            str[j + 4] = States[j];
        }

        int[] ids = new int[States.length + 4];
        ids[0] = R.id.States;
        ids[1] = R.id.r1;
        ids[2] = R.id.r2;
        ids[3] = R.id.r3;
        for (int j = 0; j < States.length; j++) {
            ids[j + 4] = j;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listval.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("listval[i]:::::" + listval[i]);

            // setListAdapter(new ExampleAdapter(this));

            /*
             * SimpleExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = new
             * SimpleExpandableListAdapter (this.getApplicationContext(),
             * groupList,R.layout.grouplayout_collapsed, new String[] {"text2"},
             * new int[] {R.id.text2}, childList,R.layout.childlayout, str,
             * getValue());
             */

            MyAdapter ma = new MyAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    groupList, R.layout.grouplayout_collapsed,
                    new String[] { "text2" }, new int[] { R.id.text2 },
                    childList, 0, str, ids);
            setListAdapter(ma);

        }

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends SimpleExpandableListAdapter {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        Context context;

        public MyAdapter(Context context,
                List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout,
                String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
                List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData,
                int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
            super(context, groupData, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                    childData, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
            this.context = getApplicationContext();
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

        {
            final int selecetdPos = groupPosition;
            System.out.println("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.childlayout, null);
            convertView.setId(R.layout.childlayout);
            table = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

            System.out.println("TABLe:::::::::::::::" + table);

            TableRow tabrow1 = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(
                    VarietyDetailsActivity.this).inflate(
                    R.layout.expandablelist_table_head, null);
            ((TextView) tabrow1.findViewById(R.id.States)).setText("States");
            ((TextView) tabrow1.findViewById(R.id.r1)).setText("R1");
            ((TextView) tabrow1.findViewById(R.id.r2)).setText("R2");
            ((TextView) tabrow1.findViewById(R.id.r3)).setText("R3");
            tabrow1.setVisibility(0);
            System.out.println("TABROW:::::::::::::::" + tabrow1);
            System.out.println("TABLe:::::::::::::::" + table);
            table.addView(tabrow1);

            for (int k = 0; k < States.length; k++) {
                // Inflate your row "template" and fill out the fields.
                TableRow tabrow = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(
                        VarietyDetailsActivity.this).inflate(
                        R.layout.expandabletable_data, null);
                System.out.println("TABLe ROW:::::::::::::::" + tabrow);

                ((TextView) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.state1))
                        .setText(States[k]);
                ((TextView) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.state1)).setId(k);

                ((EditText) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.r1_r1val)).setInputType(0);
                ((EditText) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.r1_r1val))
                        .setEditableFactory(new Editable.Factory());

                ((EditText) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.r1_r2val)).setInputType(0);
                ((EditText) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.r1_r2val))
                        .setEditableFactory(new Editable.Factory());

                ((EditText) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.r1_r3val)).setInputType(0);
                ((EditText) tabrow.findViewById(R.id.r1_r3val))
                        .setEditableFactory(new Editable.Factory());

                tabrow.setVisibility(0);
                table.addView(tabrow);

            }

            System.out.println("TABLe ROW COUNTTTTTT:::::::::::::::"
                    + table.getChildCount());

            table.requestLayout();
            table.setVisibility(TableLayout.VISIBLE);

            Button ok = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            System.out.println("Butttooonnn:::::" + ok);
            ok.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            ok.setTextSize(20);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    System.out.println("INSIDE BUTTON ON CLICK:::::");
                    System.out.println("Selecetd POs:::::" + selecetdPos);

                    String[] charValues = getTableData();
                    for (int i = 0; i < charValues.length; i++) {
                        String[] rowValues = charValues[i].split(",");
                        System.out.println("ROW VALUES Length:::::"
                                + rowValues.length);
                        if (selecetdPos == 0)
                            insertinDB(year, rowValues[0],
                                    Constants.characterstic, "candidate",
                                    rowValues[1], rowValues[2], rowValues[3]);
                        else if (selecetdPos == 1)
                            insertinDB(year, rowValues[0],
                                    Constants.characterstic, "referenceVar1",
                                    rowValues[1], rowValues[2], rowValues[3]);
                        else if (selecetdPos == 2)
                            insertinDB(year, rowValues[0],
                                    Constants.characterstic, "referenceVar2",
                                    rowValues[1], rowValues[2], rowValues[3]);
                        else if (selecetdPos == 3)
                            insertinDB(year, rowValues[0],
                                    Constants.characterstic, "referenceVar3",
                                    rowValues[1], rowValues[2], rowValues[3]);
                    }

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        void insertinDB(String year, String state, String characterstic,
                String variety, String r1, String r2, String r3) {
            final DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter
                    .getDBAdapterInstance(getApplicationContext());
            dbAdapter.openDataBase();
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

            if (variety.equals("candidate")) {

                initialValues.put("candidate_varR1", r1);
                initialValues.put("candidate_varR2", r2);
                initialValues.put("candidate_varR3", r3);
            } else if (variety.equals("referenceVar1")) {

                initialValues.put("reference_var1R1", r1);
                initialValues.put("reference_var1R2", r2);
                initialValues.put("reference_var1R3", r3);
            } else if (variety.equals("referenceVar2")) {

                initialValues.put("reference_var2R1", r1);
                initialValues.put("reference_var2R2", r2);
                initialValues.put("reference_var2R3", r3);
            } else if (variety.equals("referenceVar3")) {

                initialValues.put("reference_var3R1", r1);
                initialValues.put("reference_var3R2", r2);
                initialValues.put("reference_var3R3", r3);
            }
            dbAdapter.updateRecordRValuesInDB(initialValues, year,
                    characterstic, state);
            System.out.println("DB Updated");

            dbAdapter.close();
        }

    }

    public String[] getTableData() {
        String[] charValues = new String[States.length];

        for (int j = 0; j < States.length; j++) {

            System.out.println("TABLe:::::::::::::::" + table);

            TableRow tr = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(j + 1);
            tr.setEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("Tablerow:::::" + tr);

            System.out.println("TableRow Count:::::" + tr.getChildCount());
            TextView state = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
            r1 = (EditText) tr.getChildAt(1);
            /*
             * r1.requestFocus(); r1 .setEnabled(true); r1.setFocusable(true);
             * r1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); r1.setClickable(true);
             * r1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
             * r1.setText(r1.getText(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
             */
            System.out.println("EditText:::::" + r1);

            System.out.println("EditText enabled :::::" + r1.isEnabled());

            System.out.println("EditText Edit Mode :::::" + r1.requestFocus());
            System.out.println("EditText Edit Mode :::::" + r1.isInEditMode());
            System.out.println("EditText Text :::::" + r1.getEditableText());

            /*
             * r1.setOnEditorActionListener(new
             * EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
             * 
             * @Override public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1,
             * KeyEvent arg2) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub if (arg1 ==
             * EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) { System.out.println("TRUEEEEEEEE");
             * return true;
             * 
             * } System.out.println("FALSEEEEE"); return false;
             * 
             * } }
             * 
             * );
             * 
             * r1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             * 
             * 
             * @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             * int before, int count) {
             * 
             * // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             * System.out.println("OnText Changed EditText r1 Value:::::::::::::::"
             * +r1.getText().toString());
             * 
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int
             * start, int count, int after) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             * System
             * .out.println("Before   EditText r1 Value:::::::::::::::"+r1.
             * getText().toString()); }
             * 
             * @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { // TODO
             * Auto-generated method stub
             * System.out.println("After   EditText r1 Value:::::::::::::::"
             * +r1.getText().toString()); } });
             */

            System.out.println("EditText r1 Value:::::::::::::::"
                    + r1.getText().toString());
            r2 = (EditText) tr.getChildAt(2);
            System.out.println("EditText r2 Value:::::::::::::::"
                    + r2.getText().toString());
            r3 = (EditText) tr.getChildAt(3);
            System.out.println("EditText r3 Value:::::::::::::::"
                    + r3.getText().toString());

            charValues[j] = state.getText().toString() + ","
                    + r1.getText().toString() + "," + r2.getText().toString()
                    + "," + r3.getText().toString();

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < charValues.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("charvalue  :::::" + charValues[i]);
        }
        return charValues;

    }

}





thanks and regards
Kajal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually , The problem solved by setting the TextWatcher on each EditText in getChildView() instead of getTableData() method while initialising the EditText.Fetch the data and storing the data entered in edittext every time in any other variable. Because getChildView() get reloaded on clicking on the each editText. So the editText value need to be stored in any other variable as well to retrieve the data afterwords.

example:

@Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int
                      start, int count, int after) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      }

```
                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { // TODO
                      if((s!=null&&s.length()>0)){

                        v2 = s.toString();
                        Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "([0-9]*)" );

                        Matcher m = p.matcher(v2);
                          System.out.println("v2 :::::" + v2);

                          if(stateCount>=States.length)
                                stateCount =0;

                                else

                                stateCount = stateCount+1;
                          System.out.println("SateCount in v2:::::::::::::::" + stateCount);
                                insertInV2Array(stateCount,v2);


                        if(!m.matches())
                        {

                                Toast.makeText(VarietyDetailsActivity.this, "Please enter between 1- 9 only",8 )
                                .show();



                        }


                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a TextWatcher on each EditText which will be called when the text in the editText has been changed.

Comment: I have tried that but the control do not enter in TextWatcher... Please check the commented code in getTableData()